# return value of ((a++)) in shell

Tags: shell

I got an unexpected behavior of a shell script. Finally I found that the error is caused by the return code of `((a++))`. but I don't know why. The simplified script is as followed:

```
set -e
a=0
((a++))
echo "here"
```

The output of the script above is empty.

then I remove the `set -e` and print the return code of `((a++))` then the script becomes

```
 a=0
((a++))
echo $?
echo $a
echo "here"
```

then the output is

```
1
1
here
```

then I call `((a++))` one more time:

```
a=0
((a++))
echo $?
echo $a
((a++))
echo $?
echo $a
echo "here"
```

the output is:

```
1
1
0
2
here
```

So why is the return code of `((a++))` different when I call it two times?

Thanks very much!

Comment: `(( ))` flips the return status - `a++` returns 0, and the arithmetic evaluation considers that to be false.  Therefore, the return value of the evaluation is 1, which represents false everywhere in the shell except for arithmetic evaluation.  Yes, it is a bit strange :) .  But it follows the mental model of C, so at least there is a reason.

Comment: thanks. According to your reminder， I find more explanation here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372408/shell-exit-silently-at-arithmetic-expression-in-for-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1